# How can I read Cookie through Webhook in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, webhooks

I'm using selz.com to process payments and I can use test webhooks to my files.

For example, I have **whtest.php**.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['Affiliate']))
{
    $aff_code = $_COOKIE['Affiliate'];
}
file_put_contents('webhook_data.txt', $aff_code, FILE_APPEND);  

//WEBHOOK
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
file_put_contents('webhook_data.txt', $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

The cookie is already there. So if I go to **whtest.php** and access it directly from the browser it will write the cookie data inside **webhook_data.txt**. That's all fine.

The problem is that if I send test some random webhook data to **whtest.php** it gets it successfuly into **webhook_data.txt** but not the data from the cookie too. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the webhook call from selz.com suppose to contain cookie data?

Comment: @CJWurtz no, the cookie is already created from another page on my server.

Comment: The call from selz won't contain any cookie data then.

Comment: @CJWurtz But how can I use this cookie when the call happens? The call is sent after each purchase. I want to use the data stored previously in my cookie when this call happens to determine if there was an affiliate sale or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't use a cookie in this circumstance.  The webhook will have no knowledge of a cookie that you set for your user on your site.

I'm not familiar with selz (so sorry I can't be more specific), but you'll have to find some piece of data that is sent in the webhook that you also have access to prior to your user making the purchase.  Something like a shopping cart id, transaction id, order id, session token, etc.  Any identifier that is unique to that user's purchase.

Once you have that data, you will need to make a call to your server prior to the purchase happening, and persist in a database the relationship of this id -> affiliate_sale.  Once the webhook call is made, you then use that piece of data sent by selz to do a lookup for its match in your database.  You can then do whatever you have to do if it was an affiliate sale.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know any other alternative I can do this? Some decent online payment processors which offer affiliate options?

Comment: Offhand I'm not sure, sorry